# What is the opposite of logarithmic scale?

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

If one wants to plot a variable whose value changes drastically, it makes sense to plot its order of magnitude. That way, the smaller values in the plot aren't squished all the way at the bottom. This in turn "compresses" the axis, making the plot more readable.

Whatif I'm plotting a variable whose value changes only slightly in the domain I'm using? Then I would like to "stretch" my vertical axis, exactly opposite of what the logarithmic scale does. Is there a standard for such a system? I could just raise it to a power and plot that, but I'm looking to see if this is typically done in a certain way.

Comment: What is the inverse function to the logarithm?

Comment: I've already explained this in the problem statement. I'm not sure if I can simply exponentiate my variable. I've never seen this done, and I'm looking for something that is possibly used in other disciplines.

Comment: Suppose you are plotting over $[a,b]$, and $f(x)$ changes very slowly over the entirety of $[a,b]$. Simply shifting and linearly stretching the scale on the $y$-axis so that the minimum and maximum outputs of $f$ over $[a,b]$ are near the bottom and top of the graph would communicate all of the change in a way that made good use of your 2D display field. The only way I can imagine this being unsatisfactory is if there are brief periods with a steep rate of change. But then a logarithmic rescaling applied on top of the shifting and stretching would help. Do you have an example function?

Answer (score 1):

You can plot with exponential scaling, for example $x = 10^{x'}$. This is equivalent to plotting $\log_b f(x)$ vs. $x$.

---

To elaborate, consider a plot $P$ to be defined by plot coordinates $x', y'$ and a graph with points $x,y$.
If you want $x'$ to be "shorter" for large $x$, i.e. stretch the axis, you'd set $x=10^{x'}$ and thus $$y' = y = f(x) = f(10^{x'})$$
This is good, if $f'$ is very small.
If $f$ is very small in change, you could go for $y' = 10^y$ instead so
$$y' = 10^y = 10^{f(x)} = 10^{f(x')}$$
For very simple functions, say $f = {\rm id}$, you can interchange these equivalently with $\log$'s of the "other axis".

Comment: Is this a common approach? Have you seen this being done anywhere? Also plotting Log[f(x)] by x, is the logarithmic scale itself, not its inverse.

Comment: @cartonn Both approaches are and I thought you referred to $f(x)$ vs. $\log x$ in your original question. For example, MATLAB implements those as semilogx and semilogy, and also loglog for plotting $\log f(x)$ vs. $\log x$. Note that by equivalent I mean "result in the same image, minus the axis"

Comment: No, I specifically explained that this refers to stretching the axes. `semilogx` and `semilogy` are the log scale, not its opposite.

Comment: @cartonn In this case, use manual scaling, using the proposed transformations from my second part of the answer, chosing the Basis arbitrarily, of course.